# Can I use 2 Different Cloudflare Account to handle 1 domain

Tags: dns, webserver, domain

I handle a website for client.
The domain has configured with a cloudflare account, owned by my client.
I want to add some DNS records but with my cloudflare account.

Then I ask my client to add  my NS server (generated by cloudflare) in the domain Name servers. So the website have 4 NS server for 2 cloudflare account.

How make it works or any other  options to make it right?

Thx for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

[CloudFlare allows for multi-user accounts](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-multi-user-organizations-share-an-account-without-sharing-a-login/) but only for [Enterprise level plans](https://www.cloudflare.com/enterprise/):

> Multi-User is an Enterprise-only feature and is already in use by
>   large multinational organizations and governments. Starting today,
>   Multi-User is available for all CloudFlare Enterprise customers. If
>   you are an Enterprise customer who would like to have Multi-User
>   enabled, contact your account manager. Not yet a customer? Contact our
>   sales team.

The system works on a hierarchical approach based off a superuser:

> CloudFlare Multi-User accounts are hierarchical, with the root
>   privileges given to the account’s Super Administrator. The Super
>   Administrator can add or delete users in the organization, change the
>   permissions given to each user, and see and edit all CloudFlare
>   settings. If there is more than one Super Administrator, the Super
>   Administrators can remove each other, which is good practice when an
>   employee leaves the company or switches jobs.